# Change Margins using vanilla js conditionals

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

Hi i am doing a Vanilla JS practice to learn how to animate the margins using vanilla JS conditionals.

I am trying to make 2 divs (side by side on another) slide open towards the sides when you click on it, like a sliding door.

I want to do this with just vanilla JS even though I know that it is possible with CSS.

My function isn't working and I don't know why it isn't as the browser isn't showing any errors.

I intend to increase the right margin of the left door to create the opening effect, but I'm not sure if thats the correct direction to go about it.

**Here's my code:
JS:**

```
function opena(className){
  var dura = 2;
  var eleme= document.getElementsByClassName(className)[0];

  var jupiter = eleme.style.marginRight;
  var mars =eleme.style.marginLeft;
  window.setInterval(()=>{
    if(eleme.classList.contains('left')){
      if(jupiter!=50){
        jupiter++;
        jupiter+"vw";
      } 
      }else if(eleme.classList.contains('right')){
        if(mars!=50){
          mars++;
          mars+"vw";
        }
      }
  },dura)
}
```

*css:*

```
.pack{
  width:100%;

}
body{
  margin-left:0;
  margin-right:0;
}
.left{
  background:red;
  display:inline-block;
  width:50vw;
  margin-left:0;
  margin-right:0;

}
.right{
  background:blue;
  display:inline-block;
  position:absolute;
  width:50vw;
  padding-left:0;
  margin-left:0;
  margiin-right:0;

}

*
```

*HTML:**

```
<body>
  <div class="pack">
    <div class="left" onClick="opena('left')">A</div>
    <div class ="right" onClick="opena('right')">B</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Thanks for any assistance rendered!

Comment: You are incrementing a value but not doing anything with it. I suppose you must've missed but it should be something like `eleme.style.marginRight=jupiter+"vw";` instead of mere `jupiter+"vw";`

Comment: Hey there, thank you soo much!! It worked:) Just curious though, eleme.style.marginRight and var Jupiter= eleme.style.marginRight are the same. Will jupiter =  jupiter+"vw" be the same?

Comment: No `var Jupiter= eleme.style.marginRight` here `Jupiter` is just a number.